# How to avoid Object reference not set to an instance of an object in C# Console Project

Tags: c#

Hi I am trying to create the array of a class and assigning values to it's fields. My code is like

```
        RecordRef[] referLocation = new RecordRef[1];
        referLocation[0].type = RecordType.location;
        referLocation[0].internalId = "6";
```

But I am getting Exception Error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
What is wrong in the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have created array of `RecoredRef` objects, but you haven't created any object inside it.
You need to create instance of objects you want to use:

```
RecordRef[] referLocation = new RecordRef[1];
// create new instance of RecordRef, which is held inside your array
referLocation[0] = new RecordRef();  
referLocation[0].type = RecordType.location;
referLocation[0].internalId = "6";
```

You may also use [`object initializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

```
referLocation[0] = new RecordRef
{ 
    type = RecordType.location,
    internalId = "6"
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You have only initialized the array, but referLocation[0] is still null. What you would want to do is:

```
RecordRef[] referLocation = new RecordRef[]
{
   new RecordRef()
   {
      type = RecordType.location,
      internalId  = "6"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

General advice rather than specific to your situation:

1. Determine which line number the error is occurring on. (Visual Studio shoud tell you, as should the error message)
2. Encapsulate the potentially troublesome line of code in an `if(whatever == null)` statement and handle accordingly.

That's something to watch and plan for as this error is far too common, and far too frustrating to troubleshoot later.

Comment: Clearly @des addressed theis specific location correctly.  I'm just throwing this out there as a general pattern since user1683482 isn't checking for null references in the first place.  Good practice and all.

Comment: Sometimes you do want to just not run code when an item is null, but not always.  Sometimes it's simply a flaw in your logic, as is the case here.  Sometimes the creation of the item was skipped, broken, etc. (as is the case here).  And sometimes the variable shouldn't have been null in the first place.

Comment: truth, I just prefer using collection and object initializer for this same reason, if I know before the dimension of my array. Just a way to avoid null reference exceptions.